# Is there a way to list all the running docker containers by name?

Tags: docker

I'm aware of how to get a list of "container ID's" of all running docker containers.

> $ docker ps -q

Comment: can you grep the results?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it. Apologies for the slash at the start.

```
$ docker inspect -f {{.Name}} $(docker ps -q)
/test
/test2
```

Comment: I prefer your solution to mine, cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

maybe `docker ps | awk 'NR>1 {print $2}'` the NR>1 avoids print ID for the first line

Comment: This lists the name of the images, not the containers.

Comment: correct, it should be `docker ps | awk 'NR>1 {print $NF}'`

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a solution using `docker ps`, but you can do it using [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) (formerly [fig](http://www.fig.sh/)):

`docker-compose ps | awk '{print $1}'` will return something like this:

```
Name
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
src_bus_1
src_db_1
src_images_1
src_nginx_1
src_python_1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
docker ps | awk 'NR>1 {print $(NF)}'
```

does it

`NR>1` avoids printing the title row and `print $(NF)` prints the last column of the output.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.